# CPU is weak, is it CPU or motherboard?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard

My laptop, an Alienware M17xR3 started to run slowly lately. What happens is that sometimes it runs well, and sometimes not, I did run 3d mark benchmark and while mostly I get low results it happened a few times I got a good one.

Comparing them I noticed that the difference between them are in physics simulations so I'm assuming it's an issue related to the CPU.

Now the problem is, should I replace the motherboard or the CPU? How can I find out which is the faulty one.
My first guess would be motherboard since I'm also having a problem with the battery not charging, but before spending 300£ I want to make sure this is not an issue I can solve for cheaper.
Do you have any advice?
Could this be a software issue?

Comment: Other than overheating, which Overmind discusses, hardware either works or it doesn't.  The charging problem is unrelated to the speed issue, and I would look at the charger and battery before assuming it's the motherboard.  It's likely that neither the CPU or motherboard needs replacement.  And yes, it could be software (what you're running or stuff running in the background, intentionally or not).  It could also be that the computer is just inadequate for what you're trying to run on it.

Comment: Fixer1234, I bought my charger 2months ago do I assumed fit wasn't the problem, but indeed it was. After trying a different one everything was running normally. Pls provide it as answer and i'll vote it

Comment: Glad you got it working, and without major surgery.  No way to add an answer on a closed question (a common problem on troubleshooting questions).

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is probably overheating. Check the CPU temperature when in full load to see if that is the case. It may require cooler/fan cleaning, new thermal paste.